# XAML TextBlock and Run binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a problem where the binding of the Run does not work. 
Here's my current code.

```
<TextBlock
  x:Name="txtCompanyName"
  Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.CompanyName, ElementName=lbSourceList}"
  Foreground="White"
  FontSize="18.667"
  Height="33.667" 
  Margin="10,-0.5,0,-1.5">
  <Run Text=" : " Foreground="White"/>
  <Run Text=" "/>
  <Run Text=" " Foreground="White"/>
  <Run Text=" "/>
  <Run Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.RFQID, ElementName=lbSourceList}" />
</TextBlock>
```

I am getting the company name appears but the extra data never shows up.
Any ideas why this type of binding fails?

---

**Alternate Answer Along With Final Answer**

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="{Binding RFQID}" 
            FontWeight="Bold" 
            Foreground="#FFFFF504" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="185"> 
            <Run Text=" ~ "/> 
            <Run Text="{Binding RFQNo}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFFF504"/> 
            <Run Text=" ~ "/> 
            <Run Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="Bold" 
                                         Foreground="#FF85F35F"/>
 </TextBlock>
```

Comment: Show your [binding errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)...

Comment: Thanks. No binding errors are showing

Comment: You can use Binding in Run since WPF 4.0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You cannot use the `Inlines` (the `Run` child nodes) and the `TextBlock.Text` at the same time.

Comment: Yes you are right. That solved it. However this actually worked fine with the following 
`<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding RFQID}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFFF504" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="185">
              <Run Text=" ~ "/>        
        <Run Text="{Binding RFQNo}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFFFF504"/> 
        <Run Text=" ~ "/>        
        <Run Text="{Binding Status}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF85F35F"/>        
       </TextBlock>
`

Answer (score 0):

Also: make sure the bound value is `String`.

Another potential cause, if you're finding that a binding works in `<TextBlock Text="{Binding...}" />` but **the same binding fails** in `<TextBlock><Run Text="{Binding...}"...`:

**The `<TextBlock Text=...` binding implicitly invokes `ToString()` for non-string values, but `<Run Text=` does not.**