# WPF Binding Programmatically TextBlock Run

Tags: c#, wpf

tell me how to programmatically add binding in TextBlock to Run.

i tried using the following code

```
TxtBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("{Binding UnParityCount}") { Foreground = Brushes.Blue });
```

but there is still no binding via binding

used as an example [XAML TextBlock and Run binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882066/xaml-textblock-and-run-binding)

I want to add different color text to the textblock. found that you can do this through Run, but did not find how you can bind to Run from the code

I'll supplement mm8's answer, I did it like this and it worked for me

```
Run run = new Run() { Foreground = Brushes.Black };
                        run.SetBinding(Run.TextProperty, new Binding("IssueToday") { Source = this });
                        TxtBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-create-a-binding-in-code?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8  does this answer your question? edit: looks like someone else was slightly quicker than me

Comment: tried to do it like this TxtBlock.Inlines.Add (new Run (). Set Binding (TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding ("Parity Count")) {Foreground = Brushes.Blue}); 

but I get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `Binding` and use the `SetBinding` method to apply it to the `Run` element:

```
Run run = new Run() { Foreground = Brushes.Blue };
run.SetBinding(Run.TextProperty, new Binding("UnParityCount"));
TxtBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your decision, what is needed, it is not clear only why they closed my question and gave a link to the answer that does not answer my question.